# Dynamic assignment of json request in soapUI

Tags: json, rest, post, groovy, soapui

I have a REST request something like this in JSON:

```
{
"scopeId":"${#TestCase#scopeId}",
"scopeType":"${#TestCase#scopeType}",
"userId":"${#TestCase#userId}",
"fieldToBeEncryptedList":[
{
    "srNo":"${#TestCase#srNo}",
    "fieldName":"${#TestCase#fieldName}",
    "value":"${#TestCase#randomNumber}",
    "echoField":"${#TestCase#echoField}"
},

{
    "srNo":"",
    "fieldName":"",
    "value":"",
    "echoField":""
}]}
```

What I want to do is dynamically assign the values in these JSON requests (for example, you can see above that I have assigned a few using properties). Also, the contents of the array "fieldToBeEncryptedList" can also be dynamic (i.e may be more than 2 or 3). Please suggest how I could handle this using groovy or any other method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: While you can set fixed fields such as scopeId or scopeType using properties, setting up arrays will have to be done through Groovy. There aren't many SoapUI specific examples on how to do this, but I would look at http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html#_jsonoutput on how to create JSON from groovy objects, and look at https://thetestsuite.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/groovy-creating-valid-json-from-test-case-properties/ on how to set the request.

Comment: Solved the problem.... I have handled this using groovy scripting where I used java class in which I have getter setter and I set the value in that object. Finally after creation of Object, I set at the request of Service using property Transfer.